# String to float using data type conversions

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion

I'm having a headache trying to run this piece of code that I have. I'm trying to identify whether the value of float that i have entered will be the same data type as float. This is my coding.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, percentage;
    string sym1, sym2;
    int count;

    cout<<"Enter the first fraction : ";

    do{
        cin>>x1>>sym1>>y1;

        if(x1 != float(x1) || sym1 != string(sym1) || y1 != float(y1))
        {
            cout<<"Please enter the correct fraction : ";
        }
        else if(sym1 != "/")
        {
        cout<<"Sorry. This is not a fraction. Please enter again : ";
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }while(x1 == float(x1) || sym1 == string(sym1) || y1 == float(y1));

    cout<<"Enter the second fraction : ";

    do{
        cin>>x2>>sym2>>y2;

        if(x2 != float(x2) || sym2 != string(sym2) || y2 != float(y2))
        {
            cout<<"Please enter the correct fraction : ";
        }
        else if(sym2 != "/")
        {
            cout<<"Sorry. This is not a fraction. Please enter again : ";
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }while(x2 == float(x2) || sym2 == string(sym2) || y2 == float(y2));

    x3 = x1 * x2;
    y3 = y1 * y2;

    percentage = (x3*100)/y3;

    cout<<x1<<"/"<<y1<<" and "<<x2<<"/"<<y2<<" is "<<x3<<"/"<<y3<<"\n";
    cout<<x3<<"/"<<y3<<" is "<<percentage<<"%";

    return 0;
}
```

The piece of code that i'm trying to change is this

```
    do{
        cin>>x1>>sym1>>y1;

        if(x1 != float(x1) || sym1 != string(sym1) || y1 != float(y1))
        {
            cout<<"Please enter the correct fraction : ";
        }
        else if(sym1 != "/")
        {
        cout<<"Sorry. This is not a fraction. Please enter again : ";
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }while(x1 == float(x1) || sym1 == string(sym1) || y1 == float(y1));
```

it seems that when i entered 4 / 6 or any other related fraction formats, it reads properly. same goes to  4 * 6, it prints out the expected output. but when i entered a / 6 or 6 / a, it goes into logical error, an infinite loop. its like it is wrong somewhere in data conversions in if statements and while statements. or is it because the data type used is wrong? i couldnt trace what the problem might be. is there any solution on how to do this? please do help. Thank you in advance brothers and sisters.

Comment: Can you add comments to your code? No clue what's going on... :-/

Comment: `cin >> sym1` pumps everything left in cin since it is a string and whatever the characters, it will be accepted... What you may want to look into is a lexer.

Comment: Alexis Wilke how about stof? will it make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for any of these comparisons to return false.

```
if(x1 != float(x1) || sym1 != string(sym1) || y1 != float(y1))
{
    cout<<"Please enter the correct fraction : ";
}
```

`x1`and `y1` are floats, and casting them to float does not change their value in any way. The `std::string` comparison operators also compare the contents of the string, so this comparison will also always return true.

You are using the same statement as your loop condition, which leads to your infinite loop. Try using just `if(sym1 != "/")` for both conditions (better still: evaluate the comparison only once, and store the result in a boolean. doing things twice leads to bugs when you change something later and forget to change it everywhere).

For more details on how the `operator>>` is working, see e.g. [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)

Quote:

Until C++11:

> If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is expected), value is left unmodified and failbit is set.

Since C++11:

> If extraction fails, zero is written to value and failbit is set. If
>   extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in
>   value, std::numeric_limits::max() or std::numeric_limits::min()
>   is written and failbit flag is set.

Comment: how should i compare the numbers of x1 and y1 if the value is not a float? for example i declared them as 

`float x1, y1;`, how am i going to make it MUST BE EQUAL to the data type of the ones i declared? thats why i made it `x1 != float(x1)` so that if the variables' values is not in a float datatype, it will return false. but still to no avail.

Comment: There can be no non-float data in a float. The only reason for this comparison to be false is when the value is `NaN`, but that cannot be the case here.

Comment: all right. i will try again and come back to you. i'll show you the piece of the code when it works. thanks :)

Comment: @ShaqimiYusof I've added some info on how `std::istream` handles failure to extract the requested value.